# Angular Radio Button Not Firing On Watch

Tags: angularjs

I have a watch on `region` but it is not firing when I click on the radio button.

Am I doing something wrong or is it because radio buttons only detect change once in angular? Anyway around this without using form?

```
  <div class="filter-column">
    <div class="filter-title">Region</div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    <div class="overflow-container">
      <div ng-repeat="choice in regions| orderBy: 'description'">
        <input type="radio"
          value="{{choice.name}}"
          name="regionRadio"
          ng-model="region">
        {{choice.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
    $scope.$watchCollection(watchRMDapisPopulate,
    populateRMDfiltersView);

    function watchRMDapisPopulate() {
        return regionMarketDealerSrv.orgFilterData;
      }

      function populateRMDfiltersView(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue) {
          $scope.regions = newValue.regions;
        }
      }



      $scope.$watch('region', radioButtonRegion);

      function radioButtonRegion(regionName) {
        console.log(regionName)
        if (regionName === 'All') {
          regionMarketDealerSrv.populateRegions();
        } else {
          regionMarketDealerSrv.populateMarkets(regionName);
        } 
      }
```

Comment: Try to change value="{{choice.name}}" to ng-value="{{choice.name}}"

Comment: changed it to `ng-value` but still no success. No `console.log(regionName)` output.

Comment: How about using function as watch expression? $scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.region;}, radioButtonRegion)

Comment: no luck, if fires when the app first loads but after that no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The watch isn't able to pick up the changes correctly when using `ng-model="region"` since you are using primitive values. When you change the value you are getting a new reference. You can use a property of an object as your model and `$watch` that:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.regions = [{
    name: 'a',
    description: 'region A'
  }, {
    name: 'b',
    description: 'region B'
  }];

  $scope.selected = {
    region: 'a'
  };

  $scope.$watch('selected.region', radioButtonRegion);

  function radioButtonRegion(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal, oldVal)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div>Region</div>
  <div ng-repeat="choice in regions| orderBy: 'description'">
    <input type="radio" value="{{choice.name}}" name="regionRadio" ng-model="selected.region">{{choice.description}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah....I was using that but I have no way to set a default checked value like that. Any ideas on how to make a default checked value since I can not use ng-checked?

Comment: You can set an initial value to the `$scope.selected` object.